# I need some tips in increasing my weight and body sturcture

Tags: diet, food, weight-gain

i am here to ask how can i increase my weight, and shape up my body.

I eat following stuff daily:

Morning Breakfast at 6:00 am - Milk, Mix fruit Museli, tea 
Morning Breakfast at 10:00 am - fried egg and 3 chapatis

Afternoon lunch at 1:10 PM - vegetable and chapati - around 6 medium size chapatis

evening snacks at around 6:00 PM like sandwiches, biscuits and coffee

dinner at around 8:30 PM - rice, meat or any vegetable, sweet with dinner every day.

i m 5.6' ft and my weight is only 52 KGS after following the above diet with proper timings from March 2011

i want to increase weight and make my personality, look wise bold in group on 10 people..

Please suggest some tips  to me..

**EDIT** : I am a male aged 26yrs lives in India, and chapatis are made up from wheat flour. i have no ideal of my calories intake, how can i calculate that.

Comment: Have you searched the site to see if any information here might be useful to you? Your question is also somewhat broad, and it might be better if you narrow down on one problem (feel free to ask multiple, *specific* questions) rather than post one question asking for everything.

Comment: Downvoted due to over-generality of question. Some searching will find you plenty of general advice.

Comment: hi all thanks for your response, but i am still curious to know, as i am not able to eat more than this, do i need to falow some exercise and i do not prefer to take any supplement powder/tablets for gain weight. I want to increase naturally

Comment: [Eat more (particularly protein), lift weights, and make sure you're getting enough sleep.](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle/6836#6836)

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know what a chapati is, but I am guessing your overall calorie count is low.

How many calories are you eating a day? Are you a man or a woman?

If you want to increase your size, a man should take in more than 2500 calories a day.

Do you exercise? If you exercise, you should add to that twice the amount of calories you burn during your exercise. So, if you burn 300 calories on the treadmill, add 500 calories to your daily caloric intake.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment instead of as an answer.

Comment: If he wants more size, he needs more calories. That is his answer.

Comment: My rough estimate is 1200 calories in his/her diet per day.  This is the correct answer, if they want to gain weight, they will have to eat at least twice as much.  Also the macro-nutrient breakdown is heavy on carbs, so shifting to more protein will help too.